# How to divide a polygon into sub polygons and assign id to them

Tags: java, math, hashmap, coordinate-systems

I have a polygon with the co-ordinates

```
(1,2)
(3,2)
(1,1)
(3,1)
```

I want to divide the polygon into 9 parts and assign each part a number.For example[image]

So I tried like

```
double width =  3-1=2;
double height = 2-1=1;

subpolygon width=2/3=0.667
subpolygon height=1/3=0.33
```

Now I want to have the subpolygon id and their co-ordinates like

```
1  ->  (1,2),(1.67,2),(1,1.67),(1.67,1.67)
```

and so on.So I need a hash map like below to store the information.

```
HashMap<Integer, Double[]> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Double[]>();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you plan to map the information in the `hmap`? Also just to cross check, your polygon is a quadrilateral for now which needs to be divided into 9 parts, right? And further you need to store the part to its coordinate map?

Comment: when I assign the id I am trying to get the four co-ordinates of the subpolygon and then store those in the hash map.Yes my polygon is a quadrilateral for now which needs to be divided into 9 parts and need to store the part to its coordinate map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a hint to get started. What you really want is a clever or efficient way to loop through all the vertices of your polygon. Let's start by simply looking at the positioning of the top left corner of each subpolygon.

Starting at the top left corner of your polygon, we will first loop left to right, and then top to bottom. Let `sw` denote your subwidth and `sh` denote your subheight.

So what's the formula for top left corner of each subpolygon? Well, we start at `(min x, max y)`. This is the top left corner of subpolygon 1. Then we add `sw` to the x-value to get the top left corner of subpolygon 2 `(min x + sw, max y)`. Then the top left corner of subpolygon 3 is `(min x + 2 * sw, max y)`.

Then we need to drop down a height of `sh` to get the top left corner of subpolygon 4. This is `(min x, max y - sh)`. Then we go left to right again: `(min x + sw, max y - sh)` for subpolygon 5, `(min x + 2 * sw, max y - sh)`.

See a pattern yet? Drop down another height of `sh`, and go left to right again:
`(min x, max y - 2 * sh)`, `(min x + sw, max y - 2 * sh)`, `(min x + 2 * sw, max y - 2 * sh)`.

So if I let my index `i` range from 0 to 8 (which will correspond to your subpolygons 1 through 9), you can see that the general pattern for the top left corner subpolygon `(i+1)` is:

`(min x + (i % 3) * sw, max y - (i / 3) * sh)`.

Note that the preceding `(i / 3)` is integer (round down) division, e.g. for subpolygon 8, `i = 7`, and `7 / 3 = 2`.

I believe this is enough to get you started. I personally would have preferred to start at the bottom left corner and work left to right, bottom to top, but I went based on your numbering. You can find similar formulas for the other corners, and a bit of thinking can help you generalize this formulas into different partitions (i.e. look at the divide by 3 and modulo 3 parts).